# Click сквозь Label

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется `panel` на которой висит ивент `Click` и в ней стилизовано распихано несколько `label`. Вешать на каждый `label` ивент не хочется, как можно кликать сквозь них в панель?

Comment: _"Вешать на каждый label ивент не хочется"_ -- просто в цикле делаете `foreach(var lbl in panel.Controls.OfType<Label>()) lbl.Click += handler;`

Answer (score 1):

Если вам не критично, просто установите свойство enable=false у каждого label.
Это отключит его использование в качестве элемента управления.

Comment: Да, до этого варианта я тоже дошел, но если выключить лабель, то он перестает принимать окраску текста, а мне это важно. Текст на выключенном лабеле становится серым и не принимает никакие другие параметры.

Comment: Сделайте свой класс наследующий Label и переопределите в нем то, что вам необходимо